# Python argparse: argument in help but not in usage

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

In argparse, I want optional arguments to appear in the help list under `optional arguments:` but not in the usage text.  I can use `help=argparse.SUPPRESS` in the argument to remove it from usage but this has the side effect of removing it from the argument descriptions in the help text.

Is it possible -- and if so, how -- to suppress the argument only in the usage.

Additionally, how would I go about replacing all of the optional arguments with a consolidated `[--args]` indicator in the usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify a usage message, it is auto-generated based on the arguments.  If you don't like the auto-generated usage string, you can override it yourself at the time of creation of the parser:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(usage='my usage str')
```

You can not customize the auto-generated usage message to only suppress optional arguments, this is a use-it-or-lose-it thing.  If you want to re-use code for a customized usage generator, your best bet will be to subclass a `HelpFormatter` and override the `_format_usage` method.